# Al presionar los botones de la app para una redirección a otra activity, ésta se cierra

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

El problema que me pasa es que al momento de presionar los botones para que me redireccione a otra activity, se me cierra la app.

Este es el código del método de los botones de la clase MainActivity:

```
 //METODO DEL BOTON VOZ
public void Voz (View view){
    Intent voz = new Intent(this, Voz.class);
    startActivity(voz);
}

//METODO DEL BOTON VELOCIDAD
public void Veloz (View view){
    Intent veloz = new Intent(this, Velocidad.class);
    startActivity(veloz);
}
```

Este es el método del botón de la clase "voz":

```
//BOTON PARA REGRESAR A LA ACTIVITY RECONOCIMIENTO
public void Anterior(View view){
    Intent anterior = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(anterior);
}
```

Y este es el método del botón de la clase "Velocidad"

```
//BOTON PARA REGRESAR A LA ACTIVITY RECONOCIMIENTO
public void Anterior(View view){
    Intent anterior = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(anterior);
}
```

[image: Este es el problema que me aparece]

Comment: en gral en esta clase de preguntas piden el logcat

Comment: DISCULPA GBIANCHI??

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [ask]. Tus preguntas reciben votos negativos porque usas solo mayusculas (parece que gritas) y no das la suficiente información sobre los problemas que tenes. Te decia, que en las preguntas de android, piden que pases el logcat, para saber que error se genero

Comment: pero que es el logcat??

Comment: deberias buscarlo en google, pero es el log del sistema, que te va a ayudar bastante en saber que le pasa a tu app.

Comment: ya acabo de darme cuenta que es..ya lo investigue..pero como funciona??

Comment: @MarioNeto en la ventana de LogCat se despliega información relacionada a la aplicación, por ejemplo si se detiene la aplicación, se muestra un texto en color rojo (que indica error) donde describe cual es el problema. ¿Por cierto como llamas los métodos desde tu aplicación?

Answer (score 0):

De que manera creaste los Activity? Si fue de manera manual (crear la clase, la extendiste de AppCompatActivity por ejemplo, etc.) entonces debes revisar que esta nueva Activity esté declarada en el AndroidManifest.xml, pudiera ser este tu caso. Algo así:

```
        <activity android:name=".MiActivity">
    </activity>
```

Esto debe ir dentro de las etiquetas `<application></application>`, ya que no hay más detalles de tu problema es lo único que se me ocurre de momento.

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero y te ayude en algo:

1.- Pasar de una actividad a otra:

```
cambio.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent miintento= new Intent ( getApplicationContext (),PopUpTabla.class );
                startActivity ( miintento );
            }
        } );
```

2.- Pasar de un Fragmento a otro:

```
BCliente.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tabla_cliente= new Tbl_Cliente ();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, tbl_cliente);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        } );
```

3.- Pasar de un Fragmento a una actividad:

```
BCliente.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PopUpTabla.class);
             startActivity(intent);

            }
        } );
```